# House built of stone / stones

Tags: exam-questions

Which is the correct word between *stone* and *stones* to fill the blank in following sentence ?

> If you turn the corner you will find a house built of _______.

Actually I read two sentences one is given above and the second one was this

> He had a simple house built of stones he'd carried from his rocky fields.

The first sentence is in my book in which *stone* is used but the second sentence which uses *stones*, I found it on internet. My book says *stone* is correct in that sentence, if *stone* is correct then is *stones* in second sentence wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are right.

The first one says the house if built of "stone", as a generic material, while the second one uses "stones" because the house was built using specific stones, the ones the builder had taken from his rocky fields. For example, you could also say

> My house was built of wood

or

> My house was built of woods from a nearby forest

and both would be correct.